# I can't get Magento secure URL

Tags: magento, templates

I am setting up a new theme on my Magento site. However I am having a lot of trouble getting the image to load over https/http depending on the protocol.

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $slide['image'];?>"  alt=""/>
```

The image loads from the above code and it will always load from http.

if I change the code to:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA, Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()) . $slide['image'];?>"  alt=""/>
```

it will always load as https. It seems that `Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()` always returns as `true`

Where else can I configure the settings?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this. Providing you have enabled use secure url's in frontend and have the secure base media directory set to https:// it should all work fine as magento should generate secure url's in the frontend when you use `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $slide['image'];`. Are you sure these images do not have https url being generated, and that it's not another file causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure...It must be theme related, but I don't seem to find where to fix the issue. Do you have any other locations that I should look into?